How do I create a single list of numbers from across multiple observations in SAS? Without knowing the end amount
I have a SAS dataset that has multiple listings per person and variables (Treat_Date1, Treat_Date2, Treat_Date3) whenever they are treated. I need to take this and create a dataset with one observation per person with all of their treatment dates.
When a treatment is given it idealy would be listed as Treat_Date1 the first time and would carry to their other observations but that's unfortunately not the case. A person could have several unique Treat_Date1's and no Treat_Date2's.
Three examples
I have tried to create new variables each holding a listing, using retain and then outputing at the last per person. However I don't know how many treatments a person could have and end up missing dates.
Also I am new to SAS and bit unfamilar with some syntax. Thank you all for your help.

Can you share actual data (not photographs)?  And the desired result for that data.  Are you implying that in addition to dates stored in multiple different variables you also have them in multiple observation per person? Why is the original data like that?  What does it mean to have the date in some particular variable versus some other variable?

I recommend making a dataset with one row per treatment. So you variables might be PatientID, TreatmentDate, TreatmentType, TreatmentCost, etc.  Typically that is much more useful that one row per patient, with TreatmentDate1 TreatmentDate2 TreatmentDate3.

You can use a loop over a by group to create a csv list from all the values in the records of the group.
* presume date variables hold SAS date values and are formatted ;
data have ;
  attrib personid length=8 format=4. treat_date1 treat_date2 treat_date3 length=8 format=mmddyy10. informat=yymmdd10. ;
  input personid treat_date1 treat_date2 treat_date3;
  datalines ;
1 2024-03-10 . 2024-03-12 
1 2024-03-15 . .
1 2024-03-20 2024-03-22 2024-03-24 
2 2023-06-01 2023-07-01 2023-08-01
3 2024-03-15 . .
3 2024-04-15 . .
; 

data want ;
  do until (last.personid) ;
    set have ;
    by personid ;
    length trt_datelist $1000 ;
    array dates treat_date: ;
    do ix = 1 to dim(dates) ;
      if missing(dates(ix)) then continue ;
      trt_datelist = catx(',',trt_datelist,vvalue(dates(ix))) ;
    end ;
  end ;
  keep personid trt_datelist ;  
run ;


